# Checking the duplicate values of multiple columns in a row in a dataframe.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to check if a dataframe has multiple duplicate values in a row. For instance for this dataset, I wanted to check the number of entries that have duplicates of `'STUDY_ID'` and `'VISITCODE'`. I tried to implement it like this but got a syntax error, I dont know why.

```
bp[(bp.duplicated('STUDY_ID') == True) && (bp.duplicated('VISITCODE') == True)]
```

Isnt it possible to implement what I want in this way? If so, what would be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `&&` to `&` for `bitwise and` and omit `== True`:

```
bp[(bp.duplicated('STUDY_ID') & bp.duplicated('VISITCODE')]
```

For check duplicates in multiple columns:

```
bp[bp.duplicated(['STUDY_ID', 'VISITCODE'])]
```

Comment: wow that worked. But why doesnt && work? Does pytthon not support that?

Comment: no, python support `and` for scalars and `&` for arrays for logic `AND`.

Comment: I see, so  `&&` is never used? Or only in some situations? Because `&&` lights up green in the compiler

Comment: Hard question, I have no idea why `&& lights up green in the compiler`.

Comment: One more thing, `bp[(bp.duplicated('STUDY_ID') & bp.duplicated('VISITCODE')]` does not actually present the duplicate values of `'STUDY_ID'` and `VISITCODE'` at the same time. It just checks both seperately and compares them to the whole dataset. For instance, I want the rows where `'VISITCODE'` and '`STUDY_ID'` have duplicates in the same other row. Wouldnt `bp.duplicated()` do the work for that?

Comment: Do you need `pb[bp.duplicated(['STUDY_ID', 'VISITCODE'])]` ?

Comment: Yep bingo. Thanks!